# How do I expose the LoadCompleted method in the WebBrowser class in WPF C#?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, browser

How do I expose the LoadCompleted method in the WebBrowser class in WPF C#?

I am trying to write a C# program in wpf that retrieves the content of a web page.

The first thing I tried was to try the WebRequest and WebResponse classes.  This did not provide the actual displayed content.  WebResponse reveils the HTML code that is sent to the browser.  But I discovered that, while the page is being loaded by the browser, javascript can change what content is finally displayed in the browser.

So I decided to use the WebBrowser class.

Immediately I found that there are two WebBrowser classes.  Thee is the one that is documented for WinForms and there is another that is documented for WPF.  I need to understand the one documented for WPF.  What I think I neeed to know what to do is to retrieve code after the "LoadCompleted" method is caused.  But I do not know how to this and I cannot find any example demonstrating how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will retrieve the HTML of the requested page:

```
dynamic doc = webBrowser.Document;
var htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
```

For more information I recommened reading a bit more on the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control